# angular.js building a fully custom $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried to do this in many ways, ui-sref is not working for me ok because data make it undefined by the time it is created.

I'm quite new even programming but fighting a lot with angular these days.

The point is that is this possible to really create a fully custom $state.go?

When I say fully custom is, how can i construct even the key of the parameter?
In:
$state.go(stateName, {key:value}

Thanks

```js
angular.module('app').directive('directive', ['$state', function ($state) {


  function link(scope, elements, attibutes) {
  //variable data coming example
    data = {
      name: 'name',
      params: {
        key: 'id',
        value: 'sidvalue'
      }
    }

    scope.back = function (data) {
      $state.go(data.name, '{' + data.params.key + ':"' + data.params.value + '"}');
    }
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    templateUrl: 'path.html'
  };

}]);
```

EDIT: ********* 
This is the historic factory gathering info from each state with push and getting it from with my logic when is convenient with get:

```js
 angular.module('app').factory('Historic', ['$q', '$state', function ($q, $state) {
var historic = [];
return {
  historic: {
    push: function (key, value) {
      var str, init = 'general.home';
      str = {
        name: $state.current.name,
        params: {
          key: key,
          value: value
        }
      };

      if ($state.current.name === init) {
        historic = [{
          name: $state.current.name,
        }];
      } else if (historic.length <= 0) {
        historic.push({name: init});
      } else if (historic[historic.length - 1].name !== str.name && historic[historic.length - 1].params !== str.params) {
        historic.push(str);
      }

    },

    get: function () {
      var h = historic[historic.length - 2];
      if (historic.length === 1) {
        h = historic[0];
      }
      return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(h);
      });
    },
    pop: function () {
      historic.pop();
    },
    status: function () {
      return historic.length;
    }
  }
};
}]);
```

For getting it I'm using a directive with a bit more code attached.
Publishing only the related to historic part.

```
angular.module('app').directive('directiveName', ['$state', 'fHistoric', function ($state, fHistoric) {

function link(scope, elements, attibutes) {

  /*
  historic setup
  */

  if (fHistoric.historic.status > 3) {
    scope.home = true;
  }

  function keycomp(data) {
    if (data.params) {
      key = {id: data.params.value};
    } else {
      key = {};
    }
  }

  scope.back = function () {
    fHistoric.historic.get()
      .then(function (data) {
        keycomp(data);
        if (key) {
          $state.go(data.name, key);
        } else {
          $state.go(data.name);
        }
      });
    fHistoric.historic.pop();
  };
}

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: link,
  scope: {
    header: '@',
    state: '@'
  },
  templateUrl: 'path.html'
};
}]);
```

I really don't like the solution proposed, it is working but the problem with the key values made me to wrap some spaguetti code I really don't like to solve the id: coming from the key value.

Open to new ideas. ;)

Comment: Can you post your state definition here?

Comment: I'm creating an array keeping record of the historic of the navigation through the states organized by name and params to manage the go back between states on my own. The problem comes when calling the kept state with the $state.go when you just have the array of names and params and in params key: value situations you need to have the key variable as well.